# How to use Pusher API for bi-directional communication?

Tags: websocket, pusher

When taking a look at the [Pusher](https://pusher.com) Servcer and their [Client / Server API](https://pusher.com/docs) I am having some problems trying to figure out how Pusher will help me allow bi-directional communication between devices / apps.

I am having multiple smaller devices / apps in the field that should return their status to a server or another client, which acts as a dashboard to browse all those devices and monitor status, etc.

In my understanding this can be done using traditional `WebSockets` and a cloud-server in between which manages all connections between those clients - something I though Pusher would be.

But after reading through the docs I can't really see a concept of bi-directional data communication. Here's why:

1. To push data to the clients I have to use one of Pushers [Server Libraries](https://pusher.com/docs/libraries)
2. To receive that Data I have to use one of Pusher [Client Libraries](https://pusher.com/docs/libraries)

This concept however does not fit into what I need. I want to:

1. Broadcast to Clients.
2. Clients can send Data directly to Clients (Server acting as Gateway / Routing).
3. Clients can send Data to Server.
4. Server can send / response to unique Client.

When reading about Pusher, they state: "Bi-Directional Communication" which I currently cannot see. So how to implement that advertised Bi-Directional Communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pusher does PubSub only. Using this, you can simulate bi-directional communication: Both sides of the conversation each need to have a topic dedicated to the conversation, and you then publish to this.

This is not ideal. For something which is probably closer to what you seem to want, take a look at WAMP (Web Application Messaging Protocol), which has more than just PubSub. There is a list of implementations at http://wamp-proto.org/implementations. For a router I would recommend Crossbar.io (http://crossbar.io), which has the most documentation to help you get started. Full disclosure: I am involved both with WAMP and Crossbar.io - but it's all open source and may just be what you need.